# Asyncio StreamReader occasionally reads 0 bytes

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a simple streamreader that is listening to a TCP port for a websocket implementation. The stream occasionally reads (every 30-300 second) blank data and throws an error.

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, 'not.real.ip.address', 8888, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()

@asyncio.coroutine
def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    #Starts the connection with upgrade handshake

    while True:
        #read frame data
        first_byte = yield from reader.readexactly(1)
        opcode = first_byte & 0xf

        second_byte = yield from reader.readexactly(1)
        second_byte = ord(second_byte)
        mask = second_byte >> 7
        len1 = second_byte & 0x7f

        if len1 == 126: 
            len2 = yield from reader.readexactly(2)
            length = int.from_bytes(len2, byteorder='big')
        elif len1 == 127:
            len2 = yield from reader.readexactly(8)
            length = int.from_bytes(len2, byteorder='big')
        else:
            length = len1

        if mask:
            masking_key = yield from reader.readexactly(4)

        if length:
            payload = yield from reader.readexactly(length)
            payload = bytearray(payload)
            if mask:
                for i,b in enumerate(payload):
                    payload[i] = payload[i] ^ masking_key[i%4]

        if opcode & 0x1:
            payload = payload.decode("UTF-8")
```

Every once in a while, the following error is thrown:

```
Future/Task exception was never retrieved
future: Task(<handle_echo>)<exception=IncompleteReadError('0 bytes read on a total of 1 expected bytes',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 300, in _step
    result = coro.send(value)
  File "server.py", line 76, in handle_echo
    first_byte = yield from reader.readexactly(1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/streams.py", line 464, in readexactly
    raise IncompleteReadError(partial, len(partial) + n)
asyncio.streams.IncompleteReadError: 0 bytes read on a total of 1 expected bytes
```

I am having a hard time tracking down what is causing this. I have used tcptrack to watch the port, and nothing is coming through. Am I improperly reading from the port, is there some sort of clean up that I need to do, or does the reader occasionally misread? I have tried other read functions (read and readline), and they throw similar errors occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

`readexactly()` is a picky method. [From the documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader.readexactly)

> Read exactly n bytes. Raise an `IncompleteReadError` if the end of the stream is reached before n can be read, the `IncompleteReadError.partial` attribute of the exception contains the partial read bytes.

Since the server seems to be sending empty bytes strings sometimes, it is probably a good idea for you to put the `readexactly()` call on a *try / except* block:

```py
try:
    first_byte = yield from reader.readexactly(1)
except asyncio.IncompleteReadError:
    pass
else:
    # Rest of your code
```

You could even check if you received more than 0 (zero) bytes and buffer them if your use case requires it:

```py
except asyncio.IncompleteReadError as e:
    if len(e.partial) > 0:
        # Handle the bytes read
    else:
        pass
```